# problema de objetos em cima do outro no Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estou aprendendo a criar apps android, mas de cara aparece um erro quando vou testar o app no celular, e texto fica em cima do outro, ou qualquer objeto que eu adicionar.

[image: No meu celular]

no Android studio fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="meuprimeiroapp.studio.com.meuprimeiroapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login:"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="103dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPass"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:text="Senha:"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="460dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="460dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="98dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Isso não é erro. Você não está implementando as constraints nas views. Sugiro que você dê uma estudada em como utilizar ConstraintLayouts. Aqui é um bom lugar: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/

Comment: Hm, Valeu pela ajuda vou estudar mais sobre isso.

Comment: Ou entao muda o constraint para relativelayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando o ConstraintLayout, e ele trabalha de uma forma mais diferente...

Pra você, que está começando agora, utilize o LinearLayout como layout raiz, e depois vá colocando mais algum outro LinearLayout dentro deste raiz, para ir alocando o conteudo

Answer (score 1):

No Android Studio está vindo por padrão o Constraint Layout, mude o layout, ou se adapte ao Constraint.
Para usar o Constraint Layout você pode usar uma ferramenta que automaticamente ajusta os itens.

[image: Ferramenta do Android Studio]

Ou fazer isso manualmente, que é melhor, pois você faz da sua vontade.

[image: Create Connection]